# Fix bad superblock on logical partition

Tags: linux, partitioning

I was following http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resi...xt3_partitions and when i reboot and run:

```
root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# fsck -n /dev/sda7
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda7

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

so i ran e2fsck with all the block numbers that you need (forget exactly what tool i used to find where the superblocks are hidden) no dice

then i ran testdisk and had it look for the superblock, no results

anyone have any ideas?

fdisk -l for reference:

```
root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x97646c29

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       38912   312046593    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5              64         326     2104320   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6   *         327        2938    20972544   83  Linux
/dev/sda7            2938       38912   288968672+  83  Linux
```

To be honest it looks like I lost it... Next step if that happens is to dump the partition to an image file and hope i can find or write some software to parse through the data looking for known file headers, i think.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted doesn't work, so I'm not quite sure what you where trying to do here, but you should not run `fsck` / `e2fsck` on an extended partition. `e2fsck` is used to check  `ext2` and `ext3` partitions.

This warning

> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
>   filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
>   filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the
>   superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an
>   alternate superblock: e2fsck -b 8193

means that the partition is not an `ext2` / `ext3` partition.

If you forced the check it might even have caused some damage, and maybe that's why you "lost it".

Anyway I hope you didn't loose any important data.